# JS functions not working in Angular5 app

Tags: javascript, html, angular, foreach, angular5

**Scenario :**

- Developed a little component for pagination in my app.
- It was working almost fine, it just had a minor visual issue. However, while I was trying to fix this issue, the app stopped working. The command line console shows this:

  > ERROR in src/app/components/pagination/pagination.component.ts(34,11):
  >   error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type
  >   'NodeListOf'
- In chrome it doesn't show up anything. 
  The **problem is, as you can see, with the forEach I coded for iterating some html elements**.

Here is the specific fragment of the code:

```
changePage(page:number){
    this.fromPag = page*this.pageSize;
    let pages:NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
    pages=document.getElementsByName("page");
    pages.forEach((page:HTMLElement,index:number)=>{
      page.classList.remove("active");
    });

    let selectedPage = document.getElementById("page" + page);

    selectedPage.classList.add("active");

    this.onPageChange.emit(this.fromPag);

  }
```

- I ctrl+zed all the way to when it was working fine and still getting this error
- It gets stranger when I copied and pasted the code to stackblitz and over ther it works fine

Here is the link if you wish to check it out to help me.
[pagination-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmmjyj)

**Dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
        "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
        "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
        "angular5-csv": "^0.2.10",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "promise.prototype.finally": "^3.1.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
        "sweetalert2": "^7.26.9",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
    }
```

I hope you guys could guide me a bit.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just change forEach to for of combination https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of